# Why all my elements are aligned towards the left and my second paragraph isn't displayed?

Tags: html, css, horizontal-alignment

I have a very basic html code and all the elements are asigned to the left and my second paragraph is not displayed

```css
#bar {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <h2>title</h2>
  <p>paragraphtext1</p>
  <img src="" alt="logo" />
  <img src="" alt="logo" width="720" />
  <img src="" alt="logo" />
  <img src="" alt="logo" width="720" />
  <img src="" alt="logo" />
  <p2>hi</p2>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no such element as a <p2> although the browser will probably still render it

Comment: "*my second paragraph is not displayed*" - first: you don't have a second paragraph, but the element you (possibly think is a 'second paragraph') is shown in the demo created from your posted code.

Answer (score 0):

To make `align-items: center; justify-content: center;` rules work, add `display: flex;` as well. If you just want to align items horizontally, you can use `text-align: center;` instead of those three rules. Also, `p2` is not a valid HTML tag. Change it to `p` and it should work fine.